APC Customize UI++ CSS customisation
I've started to play around with the "APC Customize UI++" extension in VS Code and have been experimenting with the CSS styling but I'm trying to make my sidebar nice and minimal. I've managed to hide the title of the sidebar however it seems to shift the content up to fill the space of where the title was, this has left an annoying block of empty space.
I've got the following stylesheet for my VS Code:
"apc.stylesheet": {
    ".titlebar-right": "display: none !important", // Removes panel layout icons
    ".sidebar > .composite": "display: none !important", // Removes sidebar title
    ".tabs-and-actions-container > .editor-actions": "display: none !important", // Removes sidebar editor actions
  },

Please refer to Fig.1 if my explanation is not suffcient.
I've tried different justify-content, padding, etc. I've exhausted the breadth of my CSS knowledge. I have tried comparing the HTML with and without the CSS but there are no differences, so I'm stumped.
If someone with experience with CSS and/or the APC extension, could advise me of some CSS to remove the blank space for the sidebar tabs to extend the whole of the sidebar rather than just a portion of it.

Try:
"apc.stylesheet": {
    ".sidebar > .composite": "opacity: 0" },

Then to move the sidebar verticaly you could use:
"apc.stylesheet": {

    ".sidebar > .composite": "opacity: 0; margin-top: -10px" },


This doesn't really work for my use case as it still leaves the gap at the bottom of the sidebar, please refer to Fig.1 in my orginal post for clarification
